# Grails and Google PlusOne

Tags: grails, google-plus-one

The Google PlusOne code looks like: `<g:plusone size="medium"></g:plusone>`

Unfortunately, in Grails world, "g:" is reserved.

I believe you can modify the Grails library, but I'm looking for an easier way.
How can I simply ask Grails to NOT PARSE this string?

Comment: Why not use the [HTML +1 code](http://code.google.com/apis/+1button/) instead of the invalid, psuedo-namespaced, XMLish version?

Comment: I was not aware of the HTML version, testing it now, you should post as an answer

Comment: what do you mean 'g:' is reserved?  For a taglib namespace?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will answer my own question and give credit to Quentin, who commented on the question but did not write an answer (if you post the answer, I will select you as the correct answer).

There is an HTML version:

```
<div class="g-plusone" data-size="medium"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Or you may output it like this in your gsp file:

```
${'<g:plusone annotation="inline" href="http://www.anythinggoeshere_xyz.com"></g:plusone>'}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, the only solution you have is to change the taglib which you are using.

If you are using a taglib, the only thing you must do is add a static attribute named namespace with the name you want, like the following example:

```
static namespace = google1
```

Answer (score 0):

building on the [taglib solution by James Williams](http://jameswilliams.be/blog/entry/215), I was able to render a +1 button with this taglib, which I named GooglePlusOneTagLib.grooovy in my taglib folder:

```
class GooglePlusOneTagLib {

    def plusone = { attrs, body ->
        out << "<g:plusone "+(attrs.size ? "size=${attrs.size}" : "") +"></g:plusone>"
    }

    def plusoneScript = { attrs, body ->
        out << '''<script type="text/javascript">
                  (function() {
                    var po = document.createElement('script'); po.type = 'text/javascript'; po.async = true;
                    po.src = 'https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js';
                    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);
                  })();
                    </script>'''
    }

}
```

and then you just use these tags in your gsp

```
<g:plusone size="medium"></g:plusone>
<g:plusoneScript />
```

Comment: After looking at it I like the pure HTML solution better (http://stackoverflow.com/a/7219746/421356), but I'll leave mine up because it still works.